# Firefox plugin that lets you to view a control's name?

Tags: firefox, plugins

Does anyone know of a firefox plugin that allows you to view what a control's name/id is? Preferably via a mouseover or something, but if I have to right click it or something that works too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firebug. Excellent plugin.

Comment: Second the Firebug.  I was just using it today to debug a ASP.NET AJAX issue.  Excellent tool.

Comment: +1 There is an "Inspect" button in firebug, click that and mouseover the element you wish to see information on and prepare to be amazed.

Answer (score 0):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), or go old-school with the [DOM inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6622).